# Question about adjoint representation and Lie algebra

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

My question is: In Polchinski II, section 11.4, page 62, said that

> "the adjoint representation is the antisymmetric tensor, which is contained in the product of two vector representations".

May I ask why is this?

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_algebra): I imagine (book unknown) that he is talking about the adjoint of SO(N); in that case, note the generators in the vector rep  are antisymmetric tensors defining the map detailed in WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. More generally, Ref. 1 is considering an [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group)
   $$G~=~O(V)~=~\{g~\in{\rm End}(V) \mid \forall v,w\in V: \beta(gv,gw)=\beta(v,w)\}$$
   over an $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$ with a non-degenerate $\mathbb{F}$-bilinear symmetric form $\beta:V\times V\to\mathbb{F}$.
2. The [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) $${\rm Ad}: G\to {\rm End}(so(V)),$$ is defined as
   $$ {\rm Ad}(g)m~=~g\circ m\circ g^{-1}. $$
3. Here the corresponding [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra)
   $$\begin{align} so(V)~=~&\{m~\in{\rm End}(V) \mid \forall v,w\in V: \beta(mv,w)+\beta(v,mw)=0\}\cr
   ~\cong~&V\wedge V \end{align}$$
   is isomorphic to the antisymmetric tensor product of $V$,
   cf. OP's question.

References:

1. J. Polchinski, *String Theory* Vol. 2, 1998; section 11.4 p. 62.

Comment: That's a nice answer, thanks a lot!